# How do I use shortcut keys in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to start using shortcut keys in Gmail. Where are they documented? Can I just start using them, or do I need to activate a feature for them somehow?

There are lots of questions in this Webapps SO site about specific Gmail shortcuts, but this more general question doesn't seem to have been asked!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A quicker way to view (and enable shortcuts if they are disabled) is to simply press

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd>

This will display a popup with all the keyboards and also a toggle to enable or disable them.

[image: Gmail - Keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: Sweet! I didn't knew this trick.

Comment: @Alex: It's pretty handy. And quite strange considering that a keyboard shortcut works when they are disabled! :)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you have to activate a feature and yes, they are documented. See below.

To activate the shortcuts:

1. Click on the gear icon from your upper-right corner
   [image]
2. Click on **Mail settings**
3. In the **General** tab, search for **Keyboard shortcuts** - the second group from the top [image]
4. Click on **Keyboard shortcuts on**
5. Scroll at the bottom of the page
6. Click **Save Changes**

The list of keyboard shortcuts and their description/function can be found [here](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=6594).

Answer (score 1):

As to the answer given, the following update:

As per 11 April, Gmail will have activated a few shortcuts that can't be de-actived.
See following two references:

1. [Google - Keyboard shortcuts](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594)
2. [googlesystem.blogspot](http://googlesystem.blogspot.nl/2013/04/gmail-shortcuts-that-are-enabled-by.html)

Comment: This should be a comment or edited into the answer, no?

Comment: I guess you're right @AlEverett but it quite useful to read it upfront.