# Marking all further messages in a thread as read in Gmail

Tags: gmail, mute

I subscribe to a number of mailing lists which occasionally have interesting information but often contain conversations that I am not interested in. Unfortunately, these conversations can often run into hundreds of messages.

> Is there any convenient way in Gmail to mark any further messages that
>   arrive with the same title as read?

I know that it is possible to do so by setting up a custom filter, but it seems like more effort than should be necessary. A "mute" button such as the one used for Facebook conversations is what I have in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *do* have a *Mute* function in Gmail. If you have [keyboard shortcuts enabled](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20512/how-do-i-use-shortcut-keys-in-gmail/20514#20514), simply press <kbd>M</kbd> to mute a conversation.

Otherwise, click the *More* button in the Gmail toolbar, and select *Mute*, *Ignore* or whatever it is called in your language:

[image: Screenshot of the Gmail More menu, selecting the Mute option]

Comment: You're right. I have no idea how I missed that!

Comment: I don't understand why this answer gets upvoted. Muting conversion does not make further messages marked _Read_, it simply moves them to _Archive_.

Comment: @IvanBalashov It seemed the OP's _real problem_ was the large number of messages he was not interested in. If a "convenient way in Gmail to mark any further messages that arrive with the same title as read" existed, that would be one solution to the problem. Muting the conversation is another solution, one that actually exists.